# I want to add plugin files in wp theme

Tags: wordpress

I added a few lines code in plugin. I want to add that plugins file in wordpress theme to avoid to be overwritten when there is an update. How can I do this?

Comment: In that case, it will be removed when there is a theme update. Best way is to modify the plugin and its detail and maintain it yourself. So it will not update or overwritten.

Comment: Thanks you for your response, Am doing that but i want to do it like Woocommerce, Because its template files  are in theme. How can I do that with other plugins.

Comment: OK, move plugin directory in the theme folder and change the references (paths) to all dependencies to use the plugin from the theme directory. And then put this in `functions.php`

`add_action('after_setup_theme', 'load_MyPlugin');
function load_MyPlugin() { 
        include_once(get_template_directory_uri() . '/plugins/myplugin_Directory/index.php');
}`

You can adjust this code to suit your requirements.